# Mesh current analysis but with variable resistors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electrical-engineering

I can't seem to be able to introduce V0 here! [image]

Here was my working out, using 3 mesh and 4 node equations. Only one mesh equation has V0 but it doesnt seem possible to introduce it into the rest.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the equation $V_w = R_0 I_5 - R_\alpha I_1$? How did you come up with that equation?

Comment: There are a lot of extraneous equations here that aren't part of doing the mesh analysis (for example, the 4 equations N1, N2, N3, N4 that are what you'd use for nodal analysis). If you remove all the junk, it will be easier to follow your work and help you get to the right answer. Also please label your meshes so we know which $I_n$ refers to which mesh current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see is this equation:

$$V_w = R_0 I_6$$

Setting up this mesh analysis, there are only three meshes in this problem. So you shouldn't have any variable $I_6$.

$$V_w = R_0(-I_2 + I_3)$$

Assuming that the two meshes that this resistor is part of are meshes 2 and 3.

There's a similar issue with your equation for $V_4$.  There is no 4th mesh in your problem, so there shouldn't be any $I_4$ in your equations.

I think your basic problem is that you are confusing nodal analysis and mesh analysis. In nodal analysis you need to identify each branch current seperately so you have a current variable for every branch. In mesh analysis we focus on mesh currents not branch currents. There are only 3 meshes, so you should only have three current variables in the mesh analysis.